# Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args:Array<String>)
{
    println("Enter values of c and d")
    var c:String= readLine()!!
    var d:String= readLine()!!
    try 
   {
       division(c,d)
    } catch (e:Exception)
     {
       println("Exception Occured")
       e.printStackTrace()
     }
}

fun division(a:Int,b:Int){
    println(a/b)

}
```

Error:(6, 17) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected
        Error:(6, 19) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected

Comment: `c` and `d` are strings, why do you expect them to be passable as `Int`s? Use `parseInt`, or `string.toInt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing `String`s to a method that only takes `Int`s. Fix with `toInt()`:

```
division(c.toInt(), d.toInt())
```